# Get string values from txt file in App_Code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my Web Application I have a txt file that contains several string values (form the labels of my forms). 
How can I get this values from this file, like something:

Label1.Text = get the string Label1 from the constant.txt file

Is it possible, or is better follow another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better use Resources
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Once you create your resources, you can use them simply this way

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Button1Caption %>" />
```

Pretty straightforward

Comment: Thank you Marcuz, I'll try with the Resources. 
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

try this code and you can able to read txt file two ways.

(1 way)

```
        string value = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Code/t.txt"));


        string[] ar={"\r\n"};

        string[] split = value.Split(ar,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

(2 way)

```
   TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"Path of appcode");

  //Reading all the text of the file.
   Console.WriteLine(trs.ReadToEnd());

  //Or Can Reading a line of the text file.
  Console.WriteLine(trs.ReadLine());

  //Close the file.
  trs.Close();

  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Hops its help.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have to get only one value at time,
to put this as caption of my labels. 

Luigi

Comment: i had edit my code.try first way. you can get string collection with value..than utilize in your code as par your requirement.